# How to use an array element as a route element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am writing routes with react router:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
```

I have an array with the element names:

```
const page = ["Hompage", "About"];
```

How can I use the array element as a route element?

I tried to add strings of angle brackets and use the array element but it didn't work.

```
const edit = () => {
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    page[i]="<"+page[i]+" />"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to import the components you want to render in the same file you are using the array? Can you explain a bit more of the use case here? Why not just map the components directly?

Comment: I have many pages to route and I don't want to write an import line for each one

Comment: At some point you need to actually import the React component you want to render as JSX.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to import the actual components you want to render at some point, and then map the array to JSX.

Example:

```
import HomePage from '../path/to/HomePage';
import About from '../path/to/About';

const pageMap = {
  HomePage,
  About
};

...

const pages = ["Hompage", "About"];

...

const edit = () => {
  return pages.map(Page => <Page key={Page} />);
};

...
```

If you are wanting to map the `pages` to `Route` components, then it would be a similar process.

```
const pageMap = {
  HomePage: { path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
  About: { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
};

const pages = ["Hompage", "About"];

...

pages.map(({ path, element }) => (
  <Route key={path} path={path} element={element} />
))
```

At this point though, you may as well use the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-routes) hook and pass your routes config to it.

Example:

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from '../path/to/HomePage';
import About from '../path/to/About';

...

const routesConfig = [
  { path: "/", element: <HomePage /> },
  { path: "/about", element: <About /> }
];

...

const routes = useRoutes(routesConfig);

...

return routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

```js
import Home from '../Home'
import About from '../About'


const Routes = () => {
  const pages = [{ route: '/', page: Home }, { route: '/about', page: About }]

  return (
    <Switch>
      {pages.map(({route, page: Page }) => (
        <Route path={route} element={<Page />} />
      )}
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

The key here is to use the imported component as the value for your `page` key and then you can use normal JSX component syntax as you are iterating with `map`